# How do you compare values of 2 cells with values of 2 other cells using array method?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have two columns (A & B) of company names & cities.  I have another two columns (D & E) of the same.  If a certain row of A&B is not present in any row of D&E then I need to add that row of A&B to the end of columns D&E.  So basically match and if no match then add.
About 550 rows of data in A&B and 6000 in D&E.  For loop takes 73 and StrComp 357 secs.  This is just one file and I have a few thousand of these files.  The StrComp is based on - [In Excel 2010 compare data from columns and highlight values if different using macro and VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21189790/in-excel-2010-compare-data-from-columns-and-highlight-values-if-different-using). 
I tried the array method by mehow at [Fast compare method of 2 columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19567060/excel-vba-fast-compare-method-of-2-columns/19570501#19570501) - its very fast - currently compares column A with column D and appends at the end of column D in 1 sec.  Been struggling to modify it to do a 2-column (A&B) to 2-column (D&E) matching for quite some time...am I missing something fairly simple or is this too complex?  Thanks much for any help...
Code I am trying to modify -

```
Sub CompareAddArr()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim stNow As Date
    stNow = Now

    Dim arr As Variant
    arr = Range("A2:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value
    Dim varr As Variant
    Set varr = Range("D2:D" & Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value
    Dim x, y, match As Boolean
    For Each x In arr
    match = False
    For Each y In varr
    If x = y Then match = True  'this matches colA with colD - 1col-1col
    'here need something like - if x = y and a = b Then match = True (for ColB with ColE) 
    Next y
    If Not match Then
    Range("D" & Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1) = x
    'here need something like - Range("E" & Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1) = a
    End If
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox DateDiff("s", stNow, Now)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To adapt this code, you should:

1. Use a `Worksheet` variable.  That way your code isn't bound to the `ActiveSheet`
2. Get both columns of each range into your Variant Arrays
3. Loop over the arrays, comparing both items in each row
4. Exit the inner loop early when a match is found
5. Accumulate data to copy into another Variant array (this avoid accessing the sheet for each result)
6. Copy the resulting new data in one go at the end of the loops

   ```
   Sub CompareAddArr()
       Dim arr As Variant
       Dim varr As Variant
       Dim x, y, match As Boolean
       Dim i As Long, j As Long
       Dim InsertRow As Long
       Dim Newdata As Variant
       Dim ws As Worksheet

       Set ws = ActiveSheet

       With ws
           arr = Range(.Cells(2, 2), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Value
           varr = Range(.Cells(2, 5), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp)).Value
           InsertRow = 1
           ReDim Newdata(1 To 2, 1 To UBound(arr, 1))

           For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
               match = False
               For j = 1 To UBound(varr, 1)
                   If arr(i, 1) = varr(j, 1) And arr(i, 2) = varr(j, 2) Then
                       match = True
                       Exit For
                   End If
               Next
               If Not match Then
                   Newdata(1, InsertRow) = arr(i, 1)
                   Newdata(2, InsertRow) = arr(i, 2)
                   InsertRow = InsertRow + 1
                   'Like LR = LR + 1, how can I increment UBound(varr, 1) by 1 here
               End If
           Next
           If InsertRow > 1 Then
               ReDim Preserve Newdata(1 To 2, 1 To InsertRow - 1)
               .Range("D2:E2").Offset(UBound(varr, 1)).Resize(UBound(Newdata, 2), 2).Value = _
                 Application.Transpose(Newdata)
           End If
       End With
   End Sub
   ```

---

**Update** - New requirement, add unique entries only once

To add a record from `arr` only if it's not already added, test the `Newdata` array and only if it's not already in that array, add it.

I've also added a parameter to specify how many columns to process and the corresponding code

```
Sub CompareAddArrUnique()
    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim varr As Variant
    Dim match As Boolean
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim InsertRow As Long
    Dim Newdata As Variant
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim NumberOfColumns As Long
    Dim col As Long

    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    NumberOfColumns = 2
    With ws
        arr = Range(.Cells(2, NumberOfColumns), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Value
        varr = Range(.Cells(2, 4 + NumberOfColumns - 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp)).Value
        InsertRow = 1
        ReDim Newdata(1 To NumberOfColumns, 1 To UBound(arr, 1))

        For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
            match = False
            For j = 1 To UBound(varr, 1) ' <---
                match = True
                For col = 1 To NumberOfColumns ' <---
                    match = match And (arr(i, col) = varr(j, col))
                    If Not match Then Exit For
                Next
                If match Then Exit For
            Next
            If Not match Then
                For j = 1 To InsertRow - 1
                    match = True
                    For col = 1 To NumberOfColumns
                        match = match And (arr(i, col) = Newdata(col, j))
                        If Not match Then Exit For
                    Next
                    If match Then Exit For
                Next
            End If
            If Not match Then
                For j = 1 To NumberOfColumns
                    Newdata(j, InsertRow) = arr(i, j)
                Next
                InsertRow = InsertRow + 1
            End If
        Next
        If InsertRow > 1 Then
            ReDim Preserve Newdata(1 To 2, 1 To InsertRow - 1)
            .Range("D2:E2").Offset(UBound(varr, 1)).Resize(UBound(Newdata, 2), 2).Value = _
              Application.Transpose(Newdata)
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @chrisneilson thanks much, it works very fast - 3secs for the file I described in my OP.  been trying to understand each line and it's going to take me a while.  Most of my exp in VBA so far has been for loops, functions, etc. and just putting my toe in the waters of arrays:)

Comment: @chrisneilson how can I increment varr UBound by 1 if not match ( like in a for loop - if not match then, along with other stuff,  last row = last row + 1).  I tried doing UBound(varr,1)=UBound(varr,1)+1, but I guess the rules of arrays are different beasts :)

Comment: @chrisneilson also if i wanted to add an additional column for comparison eg, ABC with EFG, (Name, Address, City), does that call for a total overhaul of the code or just a matter of minor changes??

Comment: +1 for a great useful code - pls save the original code, will be very useful for a lot of people down the road I am sure!

Comment: @Sandy _how can I increment varr UBound_ You can `Redim Preserve` an array, but you can only change the upper most dimension with this method.  Thats why I dimension `Newdata` as Columns x Rows, and transpose it at the end.  Also, this is a quite time costly operation.  Thats why I dimension it as large as can possibly be needed (same size as `arr`) and `Redim Preserve` once at the end

Comment: @Sandy To modify to process three columns, follow the same pattern.  Get _all_ columns of each range into your Variant Arrays.  Compare all columns in the `If`, or to make it more general, change to `If` to a loop over the columns

Comment: @chrisneilson re increment UBound - your current code copies redundant data in A&B to D&E as many times as it finds them in A&B.  So in my for loop I was incrementing the range of D&E by 1 every time a row was added to D&E so in subsequent iteration of the for loop would get caught, and hence not added. Now your code is adding everything at the end...so what can we do to prevent copy of duplicate data to the variant array w/o time costly operation??  BTW I was trying `Redim Preserve` but couldn't get the syntax right - array method is powerful/fast, but will take time to master i guess...

Comment: @Sandy see update.  BTW if you have further new questions, please ask a new question (after doing your research!)  [See this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167804/after-answering-questions-and-also-being-accepted-require-to-help-if-questioner/167807#167807)

Comment: @chrisneilson thanx for the update buddy!  that's a lot of work,an I really appreciate!  When you have the time - somethin is prolly missing in the updated code, it's copying almost all the rows in A&B to C&D in 0 secs??  Re new questions/research - apologize buddy, was working under the assumption, get the basics and then modify for my environment - thought would be able to handle it - lill did I know!  thanks much!

Comment: @Sandy re comment _it's copying almost all the rows in A&B to C&D_ - it works for me on sample data I generated.  Maybe there's something about the real data I don't know...

Comment: @chrisneilson hmm, the data is still the same and the first version still works alright.  Is your updated code still processing the same columns (A&B and C&D) or is it different?

Comment: @Sandy both versions process columns A&B and **D&E** as per your OP.

Comment: @chrisneilson my bad, I meant A&B and D&E. ok, let me step thru your version2 and see if it reveals anything...the data is the same and version1 works alright on it??!!

Comment: @sandy just spotted a typo, updated answer, marked two line to change with `<---`.  Sorry about that.

Comment: @chrisneilson was going to report back on the `For j = 1 To NumberOfColumns` but you beat me to it :)  so yeah the updated code works even faster - 2 secs! I'll be spending a lot of time trying to get a grip on your code - I think that'll be my gateway to understanding and working with arrays!  Right now, I don't even have a clue what to do if I wanted it to process 3 cols!!  Thanks again for your help and patience!